# Why do initd scripts in /etc/init.d remain after deinstallation of the corresponding package?

Tags: package-management, scripts, systemd, init, init.d

Packages, like `irqbalance` provide an `initd` script `/etc/init.d/irqbalance` which remains after the deinstallation of the packages with `apt-get remove` and needs to be evaluated by `systemd` or another `init` manager. What is the purpose of the script after all dependencies have been removed?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `man apt-get`:

> remove
>
> ```
>  remove is identical to install except that packages are removed
>  instead of installed. Note that removing a package leaves its
>  configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is appended to
>  the package name (with no intervening space), the identified
>  package will be installed instead of removed.
> ```
>
> purge
>
> ```
>  purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
>  purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
> ```

'configuration files' means 'files in /etc'

- `apt remove` leaves files in /etc, including init scripts. Use 'remove' when there's a chance you might be reinstalling and you don't want to waste a lot of time rebuilding your fantastic config.
- `apt purge` deletes the /etc files. Gone forever.
- Nether `remove` nor `purge` deletes any files in /home, ever. Those are your problem, not apt's.

How is this relevant to an init script? Aside from the obvious (it's in /etc), you can look at it two ways: An init script configures when and how the application starts and stops...or it configures init to start and stop the application when you wish.

Comment: "Nether remove nor purge deletes files in /home. Those are your problem, not apt's." -> I'd make that more abstract and say "Neither remove nor purge delete any files which are not installed by the package", but one might say that's unrealated. Otherwise that's a fine explanation. Now I have to figure out why an init script is considered a configuration file since that's not intuitive in my point of view.

Comment: @KarlRichter Thanks for the feedback. Several edits to address.

Comment: This is an important command option.  I wish it was at least referenced in the `apt remove`  output.

Answer (score 2):

The files in /etc/init.d have no purpose after de-installation and be manually removed or purged using `apt-get purge`.

While you may think of the files in `/etc/init.d` as "scripts" or executables, they are considered by the system by configuration files that may be customized by hand. Some people do customize these scripts to add extra actions before or after a service starts.

For that reason, the system doesn't consider it safe to delete files which may have customized during a normal package de-installation.

That's why there's the distinction between the normal `apt-get remove` and  the more heavy-handed `apt-get purge`.